# Different base class depending on template parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17

Is it possible to determine at compile-time the exact base of a class template depending on its parameters? E.g. I have a class template, that accepts one argument in its constructor, and I want to extend this class with another argument, for which another constructor will be used. The problem is that this second instantiation (with two arguments) must have different base class than the one with one parameter. I can detect the proper base class with `std::conditional`, but the issue is in having both constructors in one class template. E.g.:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct X
{
};

struct Y
{
};

struct XX
{
};

struct XY
{
};


template<class T, class V = void>
struct Z: public std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<V>, XX, XY>
{
    Z(T&& t, V&& v)
        : XY()
    {
        // do smth with t and v
    }

    Z(T&& t)
        : XX()
    {
        // do smth with t
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = Z(X(), Y());
    auto b = Z(X());         // <-- this instantiation fails
}
```

Here `Z(X(), Y())` works, but for `Z(X())` it fails with compile error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Z<X, void>':

main.cpp:39:19:   required from here

main.cpp:23:5: error: forming reference to void

   23 |     Z(T&& t, V&& v)

      |     ^
```

**Update:**

Tried to make the two-args ctor a template with `enable_if`, but it does not work (same `forming reference to void` as in the original code):

```
    template<class = std::enable_if<! std::is_void_v<V>>>
    Z(T&& t, V&& v)
        : XY()
    {
        // do smth with t and v
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add the lines where you attempt to instantiate the template?  I.e. the lines referred to in the error message.

Comment: Added comment in the source code listing (the second instantiation with one argument).

Comment: This looks like a case for using `std::enable_if` on your ctor(s).

Comment: @Matthew: Note that the constructor must be a template to SFINAE it away (and even then it requires some subtlety to delay the substitution failure).

Comment: Yes, I'm using C++17

Comment: @Student4K: That doesn’t say whether CTAD is important to your use case.  (Some approaches might prevent or at least make more cumbersome its use.)

Comment: @davis-herring I would prefer to be able to declare instances of ```Z``` without specifying template parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach for advanced conditional class definition is a dependent base class:

```
struct B1 {};
struct B2 {};

template<class T>
struct Z1 : B1 {
  Z1(T&&) : B1() {}
};
template<class T,class V>
struct Z2 : B2 {
  Z2(T&&,V&&) : B2() {}
};

template<class T,class V>
using Z0=std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<V>,Z1<T>,Z2<T,V>>;

template<class T,class V=void>
struct Z : Z0<T,V> {
  using Z0<T,V>::Z0;
};
template<class T> Z(T) -> Z<T>;
template<class T,class V> Z(T,V) -> Z<T,V>;
```

The deduction guides are needed because only the primary template (without its inherited constructors) is considered for CTAD.

If the `Z` that results from this transformation has no members of its own, C++20 may offer an opportunity to use (what is here called) `Z0` directly, since it supports CTAD for alias templates.

Answer (score 2):

Not an elegant solution, but seems can [work](https://godbolt.org/z/vWDnyd), use partial specialization and deduction guide.

```
template<class T, class V>
struct Z: public XY
{
    Z(T&& t, V&& v)
        : XY()
    {
        // do smth with t and v
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Z<T, void> : public XX
{
    Z(T&& t)
    : XX()
    {

    }
};

template <class T>
Z(T&& ) -> Z<T, void>;
```

Comment: That will compile. However, it looks like it is not possible to directly reuse ```Z<T>``` members in ```Z<T, V>```, since ```Z<T>``` as template specialization cannot be referenced before the general template ```Z<T, V>``` is defined. So, if ```Z<T, V>``` is meant to be "mostly like Z<T>, plus some minor functionality relevant to V instance", that won't be directly possible, or at least I do not see how.

Comment: @Student4K Yes, i admit that this is not a "good" solution. I just give one‘s humble opinion in the hope of eliciting better ones. Just based on this solution, if one's want to reuse as more as possible, maybe add an extra abstraction layer, like pimpl?